# open secound curl like in new tab (first one stay open)

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I want to fill a form with curl, which loads inside an `iframe` in panel page that appears after login. I am already logged in with curl and getting the contents of the panel page, but can't set javascript for `iframe` to show `post.aspx`. When I try to directly load `post.aspx` I get a redirect.

In the browser, same things happen---no direct access exept when I leave a panel page open and open `post.aspx` in a new tab. But when I send a `curl` to `login.aspx` and do not close it before `curl` for `post.aspx`, how can I do this with curl?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an ASP.net application, most likely it's setting several cookies on your login such as an asp.net session id.  You'll need to get the cookie values out of the initial login request and send those on each new request in order to stay logged in to the app.  You'll also need to see if the post page requires any parameters that are set via the JavaScript that you mentioned and manually supply them in your curl request.

However, it might be easier not to use curl for this and instead use a web driver to run a browser to do the requests for you such as phantomjs or a scripted webkit instance.

Answer (score 0):

i find out how to do that but another problem shows up.
this is the way that can open the post.aspx page and keep panel page(default.aspx) open ,here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/$rand.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/$rand.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://blogfa.com/Desktop/Login.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=".$viewstate."&__EVENTVALIDATION=".$eventvalidation."&master%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Uid=".$user."&master%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Password=".$pass."&master%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnSubmit=%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF+%D8%A8%D9%87+%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%B4+%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AA"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
$Cpanel = curl_exec($ch);;
preg_match_all( '#<a href\="Post\.aspx\?t\=(.*?)" target#', $Cpanel, $seasonid);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://blogfa.com/Desktop/Post.aspx?t=".$seasonid[1][0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
$res = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all( '#id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />#', $res, $poststate))
$postviewstate = urlencode($poststate[1][0]);
preg_match_all( '#id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />#', $res, $postvalidation);
$posteventvalidation = urlencode($postvalidation[1][0]);
preg_match_all( '#<input name="txtDay" type="text" value="(.*?)" maxlength="2" id="txtDay" title#', $res, $day);
preg_match_all( '#<input name="txtMonth" type="text" value="(.*?)" maxlength="2" id="txtMonth"#', $res, $Month);
preg_match_all( '#<input name="txtYear" type="text" value="(.*?)" maxlength="4" id="txtYear"#', $res, $Year);
preg_match_all( '#<input name="txtMinute" type="text" value="(.*?)" maxlength="2" id="txtMinute"#', $res, $Minute);
preg_match_all( '#<input name="txtHour" type="text" value="(.*?)" maxlength="2" id="txtHour"#', $res, $Hour);
// send  post
$res = curl_exec($ch);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/$rand.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/$rand.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://blogfa.com/Desktop/Post.aspx?t=".$seasonid[1][0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "__VIEWSTATE=".$postviewstate."&__EVENTVALIDATION=".$posteventvalidation."&hasextended=false&txtTitle=".$posttitle."&txtContent=".$postcontent."%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E&txtExtended=&btnPublish=%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA+%D9%85%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A8+%D9%88+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C+%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%AF&txtTags=".$posttags."&cmbCommentType=9&txtDay=".$day[1][0]."&txtMonth=".$Month[1][0]."&txtYear=".$Year[1][0]."&txtMinute=".$Minute[1][0]."&txtHour=".$Hour[1][0]."&chkAutomateTime=on&txtPostPW=");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
$posted = curl_exec($ch);
```

here is a new problem:
 every time that post.aspx load,it has a new validation and state.
so in my code i first open post.aspx and get validation and state and date values,then make a header and post it,i think when i try to post, its in a new post.aspx and have a  new validation and state,so wrong.
when i echo content of $posted i get an error page that says form is not complete..
any help pls....